# Software Center: package can be found but not installed?

Tags: 11.10, software-center, package-management

I'm trying to look at a package, e.g. Emerald themes.

It appears in the list but when I go to look at it, this message appears:

> There isn't a software package called "emerald" in your software sources.

What software sources do i need to add? And if they aren't already included then why does the package appear on the list?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug in Software Center: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/751504

Emerald has been removed from Ubuntu due to the package being in bad shape. However, you can try to manually download it from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emerald/0.8.8-0ubuntu1